# Como posso verificar variáveis iguais dentro de um while

Tags: php, mysqli

Como posso verificar variaveis iguais dentro de um while?

- Tipo se existir linhas como o mesmo CÓDIGO faça algo...

A Baixo coloco meu exemplo

```
$bd = new MySQLiConnection();   
$sql3 = $bd->prepare( "SELECT * FROM agenda_saidas WHERE id_transfer = ? ") or exit( $mysqli->error );
$sql3->bind_param('i', $id_transfer);
$sql3->execute();
$resultcar = $sql3->get_result(); 
while( $row = $resultcar->fetch_assoc() )
{                              
$os = $row['os'];
$nome = $row['nome'];
$data = $row['data'];


if(// se $os duplicado ){
$corlinha ='red';
}else{
$corlinha ='white';  
}
```

Exemplo: Imagine essa linhas a baixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se levar em consideração que possam existir muitos códigos duplicados, acho que a melhor solução nesse caso é utilizar o próprio SQL e fazer um GROUP BY com o campo ID, contando quantos elementos tem em cada grupo...

Answer (score 2):

Neste caso você pode já trazer esta informação do banco de dados, fazendo uma verificação para cada linha. Segue um exemplo baseado no seu código:

**Query:**

```
SELECT
    os,
    nome,
    data,
    (
        CASE
            WHEN EXISTS(
                SELECT
                    os
                FROM
                    agenda_saidas AS asd
                WHERE
                    id_transfer = 1
                    AND ags.os = asd.os
                    AND ags.id <> asd.id
                LIMIT 1
            ) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS duplicado
FROM
    agenda_saidas AS ags
WHERE
    id_transfer = ?;
```

**PHP(if)**

```
if ($row['duplicado']) {
    $corlinha ='red';
} else {
    $corlinha ='white';  
}
```

Segue um fiddle com o exemplo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/WoAPxJ6DazzS44hhwHshq/2

Comment: Ola Não funcionou  deu esse resultado  ( red red red red red ) mais teria que ser esse ( red red white red red )  os 1 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 3

Comment: @FabioHenrique realmente ficou faltando validar se a os existia mas com um id (chave primária) diferente. Alterei o exemplo e incluí um fiddle rodando o exemplo

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma variável (`$anterior`) que armazena o registro anterior, para depois fazer a comparação. Lembre de atualizar ela com o valor atual no final do while.

```
$anterior = array('id' => 0);
while($row = $resultcar->fetch_assoc() ){                              
    if($anterior['id'] == $row['id']){
        $corlinha ='red';
    }else{
        $corlinha ='white';  
    }
    $anterior = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma rotina bem simples.

No final do while atribua o valor da variável `$os` a uma nova variável, por exemplo `$oldOs`. Feito isso, a cada iteração haverá uma comparação do novo valor de `$os` com `$oldOs` ou seja `if($oldOs==$os){`

```
......
$os = $row['os'];
$nome = $row['nome'];
$data = $row['data'];

if($oldOs==$os){
  $corlinha ='red';
}else{
  $corlinha ='white';  
}

$oldOs=$os;
..........
```